# String parsing in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, string-parsing

I have a string which I need to parse in ruby, for example:

```
a = '"a,b","c,d","e,f"'
```

I'm using Postgres as a database, and using the below returns a different output.

```
# example:
a = '"a,b","c,d","e,f"'
a.split('"')
#=> ["", "a,b", ",", "c,d", ",", "e,f"]
```

The expected output is `["a,b" "c,d","e,f"]`

Comment: You example is Ruby-only. How is this related to Postgres?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String#split` with a regular expression for that.

```
str = '"a,b","c,d","e,f"'
  #=> "\"a,b\",\"c,d\",\"e,f\""
```

```
arr = str.split(/(?<="),(?=")/)
  #=> ["\"a,b\"", "\"c,d\"", "\"e,f\""] 
puts arr
"a,b"
"c,d"
"e,f"
```

The regular expression reads, "match a comma preceded by a double quote (`(?<=")` being a *positive lookbehind*) and followed by a double quote (`(?=")` being a *positive lookahead*). (In fact, for the example given one need only include one of the positive lookarounds.)

Comment: In your explanation, you have used the wrong one `(?<=")`  instead of `(?=")`

Answer (score 1):

Your string seems to contain comma separated values, so you could utilize Ruby's CSV library:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.parse_line('"a,b","c,d","e,f"')
#=> ["a,b", "c,d", "e,f"]
```